# passing Mat Autocomplete selected value to Child Component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material2

After the user selects a value from the Angular Material Autocomplete, I want to pass that value to a child component.

I'm able to get the selected value by using the optionSelected output eventemitter available in the api.  But I'm not sure what the best or simplest way is pass the value to the child component.

I'm pretty sure I can use a service as the intermediary, but I thought I could declare an Input property in the child component.

Here is the code:

programs.component.html

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ProgramName" aria-label="ProgramName"
      matInput [formControl]="programNamesControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" size="14" >
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='getSelectedProgram($event.option.value)' >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" width:100px>
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <app-program-names-detail programNameSelected="programNameSelected" *ngIf="loadProgramDetails"></app-program-names-detail>
</form>
```

program.component.ts

```
import { ProgramService } from './../program.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-programs',
  templateUrl: './programs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./programs.component.css']
})
export class ProgramsComponent implements OnInit {
  programNamesControl = new FormControl();
  programNames: string[] = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
  programNameSelected: string;
  loadProgramDetails: boolean;

  constructor(private programService: ProgramService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.programService.getProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
      this.programNames = data;
    });

    this.filteredOptions = this.programNamesControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log('Inside filter..');
    return this.programNames.filter(programName =>
      programName.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  getSelectedProgram(programNameVal) {
    this.loadProgramDetails = true;
    this.programNameSelected = programNameVal;
    console.log('Program Selected is: ' + this.programNameSelected);
  }
}
```

program-names-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-program-names-detail',
  templateUrl: './program-names-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program-names-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProgramNamesDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('programNameSelected') programNameSelected: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('program Name Selected: ' + this.programNameSelected);
  }
}
```

I haven't changed program-names-detail.component.html.

The console log shows:

program Name Selected: programNameSelected

Comment: Have you tried passing value instread of string `[programNameSelected]="programNameSelected"` ?

Comment: That worked. Thanks!